# How do I get the node number of each worker_group in Prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Anyone knows how I can get the node number of each worker_group in Prometheus?

Comment: You would probably have to be a lot more specific, like what metrics data are you even talking about?

Comment: You need to add more information. Which version of Kubernetes do you have, how did you deploy it? How is deployed also Prometheus and what did you already do?